# Possible failure reasons of a PMOS which is driving an inductive load

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

We have a product that has a vibration motor to warn users in some situations. In the legacy version of this board, following scheme has been used.

[image: PCB schematic]

After production, some of those products are vibrating continuously or not vibrating at all. When we put multimeter in diode mode and measure between gate and source, we observe that it conducts in both ways.

Possible reasons of the failure might be:

- Exceeding Drain-Source breakdown voltage which is -20V for IRLML6302 (We observed drain-source voltage using an oscilloscope when an healty device was vibrating. It was nowhere close -20V.)
- Exceeding Gate-Source breakdown voltage which is +-12V (We didn't observe this happening either)
- Exceeding continuous (-0.54A) or pulsed source current (-4.9A) (We checked the continous current but couldn't check for pulsed.)
- ESD
- Faulty part

Can battery - motor inductance or high Rds value (Due to not getting MOSFET into saturation region) somehow lead MOSFET to failure? What might be other reasons for this? Is there any obvious problems with this scheme?

By the way the logic level is 3.3V, the motor is similiar to used ones in mobile phones and we do not allow battery level to drop below 3.4V in the firmware. This problem occurs in approximately %15 of the produced devices.

Comment: Is vbat different to the logic voltage? If it is, then you’ve got some gate voltage when you want none. This means you might be killing the mosfet by overheating it.

Comment: @Kartman yes, it is. I accept that it's a design problem. When logic control pulled low, there will be ~41mV at gate terminal. Will this cause a problem?

Comment: when the logic is pulled high you have 4.2V - 3.3V on the gate. I'd say that would be a problem. Note - we are only concerned with the source-gate voltage.